# getting error in GetPixel() function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

getting error in getpixel funtion.....although used all the namespaces required for image comparison.....i am making windows app in visual studio 2013....
and do i need to define the getpixel() function anywhere...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using picture.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Expression.Drawing;

namespace picture {
    public partial class MainPage: PhoneApplicationPage {
        // Constructor

        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();

            BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage();
            image1.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@
            "Assets/WP_20150925_09_20_03_Pro (2).jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            BitmapImage image2 = new BitmapImage();
            image2.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@
            "Assets/WP_20150925_09_20_03_Pro.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }


        private double get_Percentage_Method(WriteableBitmap wb1, WriteableBitmap wb2) {
            var img1 = wb1;
            var img2 = wb2;

            // Validation of image size code  
            int width1 = img1.PixelWidth;
            int width2 = img2.PixelWidth;
            int height1 = img1.PixelHeight;
            int height2 = img2.PixelHeight;
            if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Images dimensions mismatch");
            }
            long diff = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++) {
                    // get same position pixel of both WirtableBitmap Image object  
                    Color color1 = wb1.GetPixel(i, j);
                    Color color2 = wb2.GetPixel(i, j);
                    // converting each value iGetPixelnto Integer  
                    int r1 = (int) color1.R;
                    int g1 = (int) color1.G;
                    int b1 = (int) color1.B;
                    int r2 = (int) color2.R;
                    int g2 = (int) color1.G;
                    int b2 = (int) color1.B;
                    // calculating difference between RGB color value and adding it in Diff variable.  
                    diff += Math.Abs(r1 - r2);
                    diff += Math.Abs(g1 - g2);
                    diff += Math.Abs(b1 - b2);
                }
            }
            // Converting difference into percentage and then retun it.  
            double n = width1 * height1; //* 3;  
            double p = diff / n / 255.0;
            MessageBox.Show("diff percent: " + (p * 100.0));
            return (p * 100.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an error in that line

```
  Color color1 = wb1.GetPixel(i, j);
```

which is because `wb1` is of type `WriteableBitmap` in

```
   private double get_Percentage_Method(WriteableBitmap wb1, WriteableBitmap wb2)
```

which is in turn because of the `WriteableBitmap` class not having a `GetPixel()` method, as you can see in [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Either use another class as input (e.g. a plain `Image` or `Bitmap` will already do), or work around it by using the `CopyPixels()` method ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in which you will have to pass an array of the coordinates of the pixels you want, with other image-related parameters.

Comment: thanks for this much help....please elaborate more...i have replaced the WriteableBitmap class with BitmapImage class .....but it is still giving the same error..

Comment: how to get the pixel of a WriteableBitmap?

Answer (score 0):

your wb1/wb2 are of type [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not have the function `GetPixel()`. I *assume* you're thinking about [Bitmap.GetPixel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx).

I recommend asking another question about how to get the pixel of a [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)